# How to extend entity classes with custom functions (business logic) in cakephp v3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 3 (3.3.5, that is) I want to extend my entity classes with custom functions (business logic).  For example:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Something extends Entity {
    public function isFoo() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The corresponding table object looks like this:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use App\Model\Entity\Something;   // produces an `unused import' warning

class SomethingsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

In the controller, I use this code to retrieve the entity from the database and call the custom function:

```
class SomeOtherController extends AppController {
    ...
    $this->loadModel('Somethings');
    $thing = $this->SomethingsTable->get($id);
    if ($thing->isFoo()) { ... }
    ...
}
```

However, this fails with a fatal error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\Entity::isFoo()
```

Note, when I do a

```
<?= var_dump($thing,true); ?>
```

in the corresponding view, $thing is shown as of type `Cake\ORM\Entity`.

How can I change the table's get() function to return entities with the correct type "Something" ?

Comment: Note, as a work-around I currently put the custom function in the SomethingTable class and pass the entity as argument.  This works, but I'm looking for a "nicer" solution.

Comment: Did you put the correct namespaces on `Something`? How do obtain `$this->SomethingsTable`? Did you create a `SomethingsTable` class or do you use the default one?

Comment: as @Holt says you should have something like `use App\Model\Entity\Something`; in your SomethingsTable. Try `debug($thing)` and see if it is a thing entity or a generic entity

Comment: @Holt and @arilia: thanks for your help!  I've updated the code excerpts above.   The `SomethingsTable` is the default one, created with the `bake` command.  Adding the `use App\Model\Entity\Something` in the table class didn't change anything--the import is reported to be 'unused'.  Would it help to overload the SomethingsTable->get() method in my custom class ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
$thing = $this->Somethings->get($id);

// not 
$thing = $this->SomethingsTable->get($id);
```

Thats why the `Something` entity is not used, but the default `Entity` class.

CakePHP autotables, since it can not find the SomethingsTable**Table** the default table class is used. Therefore also the default entity class is loaded. 
If your test method would contain a query to the db, there would have been an error thrown, saying that somethings_table does not exist.

Comment: You are right, thanks!  However, my problem actually was that cakephp

Comment: You are right, thanks! However, my problem actually was that cakephp's Inflector class didn't handle my camel cased German word correctly (I renamed the class to SomethingsTable just for this example).  I just filed a bug report in github for this: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9620  So, my conclusion: if cakephp's table->get() can't find the custom entity class, it will fall back to Cake\ORM\Entity silently...

Comment: Yes actually i think this is a feature. If the db table has no special behavior, you dont have to create a table and entity object, cake will use the default table and entity object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably here:

```
class SomeOtherController extends AppController {
    $this->loadModel('Somethings');
    $thing = $this->SomethingsTable->get($id); // <-- Here
    if ($thing->isFoo()) { ... }
}
```

[`Controller::loadModel`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models) does not set `$this->SomethingsTable` (which was probably set somewhere else in your code... ), but `$this->Somethings`, so this should be:

```
$this->loadModel('Somethings');
$thing = $this->Somethings->get($id);
if ($thing->isFoo()) { }
```

This code works, you do not need `use App\Model\Entity\Something` in `SomethingsTable.php`.

When trying to debug such thing, use `debug()` instead of `var_dump`:

```
Configure::write('debug', true); // If you are not already in debug mode
$this->loadModel('Somethings');
debug($this->Somethings);
```

Output:

```
object(App\Model\Table\SomethingsTable) {

    'registryAlias' => 'Somethings',
    'table' => 'somethings',
    'alias' => 'Somethings',
    'entityClass' => 'App\Model\Entity\Something', // Good!
    'associations' => [],
    'behaviors' => [],
    'defaultConnection' => 'default',
    'connectionName' => 'default'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I faced this issue today and the solution for me was slightly different. I was loading the model the right way, but my class name was not following naming conventions.

My Table: JobProfitsTable.php

My Entity: JobProfit**s**.php (plural)

CakePhp is automatically looking for class named JobProfit.php (singular), and seems to fallback on Cake\ORM\Entity

So I had 2 options:

1. Rename my entity into JobProfit.php
2. Update my Table class with `$this->setEntityClass('JobProfits')`

Comment: For some naming convention I ignore my model "Poi" (with PoisTable) doesn't work and fallbacks to Cake\ORM\Entity entity class name.
Adding `$this->setEntityClass('Poi');` to my table initialize method it works well! Thanks a lot